# How to open gimp from a gtk program and pass GdkPixbuf?

Tags: c, gtk, gimp, gdkpixbuf

I have a GdkPixbuf object representing an image, I display this image in my program.

Currently the user can save this image and open gimp to load it. Is it possible to open gimp directly from the c program and pass the GdkPixbuf object to gimp?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be linked between two programs to transfer an object! Maybe you have to write a Gimp plugin or `#include <gimp.h>`

But using a virtual in-memory file (like FIFO) is probably easier, if you are on Linux (or another Unix).
See:

```
man mkfifo
```

and

```
man 7 fifo
```